# How To Increase frontend session timeout to 10 day In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, php-5.6

I am trying to increase session time out limit to **10 days** in magento for non logged in customer but it is expiring before may be witthin 1 days. I went to `System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie management` and set **864000** value for the field Cookie Life time but still it is not expiring the session in specified time out limit. I don't know what is wrong with Magento frontend session.

My .user.ini  file contains

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 864000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 864000
memory_limit = -1
date.timezone = Asia/Kolkata
session.save_handler = redis
```

Cookie time is also correct. *My Current time is 29/07/2017 03:41*

[image: cookie setting]

Am I setting the limit at right place? Is there any other setting in magento backend to set the frontend session time out limit. server managed by serverpilot and also using cloudflare

**UPDATE***

- I'm using redis server. local.xml files contains

  [image]
- found in domain header

> set-cookie:frontend=33955232e53750ff997a3b8391324b1c;
>
> expires=Tue, 08-Aug-2017 10:45:53 GMT;
>
> Max-Age=864000; path=/;
>
> domain=example.com

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that the session has expired?  If carts are being emptied after one day, check quote lifetime.

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/sales/shopping-cart-quote-lifetime.html